# Java 8 stream - how to find parent entity from child?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a scenario similar to:

```
public class A {
    private String id;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<B> bSet;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class B {
    private String id;
    // other attributes
    // getters and setters
}
```

How can I find an instance of `A` when I have an instance of `B` using the `stream()` API? I was trying something like:

```
public A findAFromB(B b) {
    List<A> aList = aService.findAll();
    Optional<A> matchingObject = aList.stream().filter({find a where a.getBSet().contains(b)}).getA();
return (A) matchingObject.get();
}
```

How to properly write this filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soemthing like using a `findFirst` or `findAny` as a terminal operation:

```
Optional<A> matchingObject = aList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getbSet().contains(b))
        .findFirst();
```