# Java 8 stream - how to find parent entity from child attribute or set of child attribute?

Tags: java, java-stream

This is a next step up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288707/java-8-stream-how-to-find-parent-entity-from-child/56288765#56288765) I posted before.

The scenario now is similar to:

```
public class A {
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<B> bSet;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class B {
    private String id;
    // other attributes
    // getters and setters
}
```

How can I find an instance of `A` when I have an instance of `B` using the `stream()` API? I was trying something like:

```
public A findAFromB(B b) {
    List<A> aList = aService.findAll();
    Optional<A> matchingObject = aList.stream()
        .filter(/*find whether a.getB().equals(b) OR a.getBSet().contains(b)*/)
        .getA();
    return (A) matchingObject.get();
}
```

How to properly write this filter?

Comment: Literally pretty much exactly how you've already written it `a -> a.getB().equals(b) || a.getBSet().contains(b)`

Comment: I hope that `findAll` does not get all objects from a database just to filter on java side. If this is the case, it would be better to filter directly in the database request.

Comment: I thought so, strangely enough, it is returning `null`... Let me double check if I missed anything...

Comment: @Michael Wouldn't it be better to check `equals()` on `id` instead of whole object ? I think that the default `equals()` implementation will not work.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle That's a consideration. I had assumed that a proper `equals` implementation was part of the class that he'd omitted - not necessarily a good assumption, in retrospect.

Comment: @gtludwig Can you add this method in class B : ` public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
  B b = (B) o;
  return Objects.equals(id, b.id);
 }`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, I am using a `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder` for the equals method and it is defined as `public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this :

```
public static A findAFromB(B b) {
    List<A> aList = aService.findAll();
    return aList.stream()
            .filter((A a) -> a.getB().equals(b) || a.getBSet().contains(b))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

But it won't work with the default implementation of `B::equals()`, which is this one :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

i.e. 2 objects of class `B` will equal only if they are the very same instance.
If you create 2 objects of class B with the same value for the every field, `equals()` will still return `false`. Here is an example :

```
B b1 = new B();
b1.setId("1234")

B b2 = new B();
b2.setId("1234")

System.out.println(b1 == b1); // displays true
System.out.println(b1.equals(b1)); // displays true
System.out.println(b2 == b1); // displays false
System.out.println(b2.equals(b1)); // displays false
```

In your case, there are some object of class `B` that are created automatically by JPA. It means that there can be distinct objects of class `B` with the same `id` in the memory.

You can give your own implementation of `equals()`. Every decent IDE has a way to auto-generate it. For example, here, it seems reasonable to consider that 2 `B` instances equal if they have the same `id` :

```java
public class B {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    B b = (B) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, b.id);
  }
}
```

```
System.out.println(b1 == b1); // displays true
System.out.println(b1.equals(b1)); // displays true
System.out.println(b2 == b1); // displays false
System.out.println(b2.equals(b1)); // displays true
```

Comment: how would you implement the findAll() to the database request? I was considering something like My JpaRepository interface is `A findByBEqualsOrBSetContains(B b)`, but spring data is saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available for part bSet CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains] NEVER.`

Comment: I did not practice JPA for a while. It seems that `Contains` is meant to work with Strings. Maybe you would have better luck trying to build something with a `IN` clause, like you would in SQL.

Comment: I did a very ugly hack by creating 2 distinct methods to JPA interface... one that looks for `b` and one that looks in `bSet`... very, very ugly!

Comment: @gtludwig If it gets too complicated to have a correct method name, you can annotate the method with `@Query` and directly request what you want. e.g. `@Query("select u from User u")`

Comment: Yes, there is always this option!